# how to code a sidenav like material.angular.io did

Tags: angular, navigation, sidenav

> I also asked this question in Github [@angular/components](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/19163) Issues, there is a screenshot on it.

## What are you trying to do?

I`m trying to write a Sidenav skeleton demo, just like official document https://material.angular.io/ navigation skeleton(A menu in the left part and content body in the right part with overview\api\examples tabs).

And I`m new to Angular, I cannot figure out how to code this Sidenav skeleton, and I can not find where is the relevant source code about this skeleton after I cloning this repo.

If anyone can help me, I'll be much appreciated.

## What troubleshooting steps have you tried?

I have already read the [Sidenav Document](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview), and still don't understand.

Because according to this document, I need to code Sidenav as follows, but in Official Sidenav skeleton, it's class called `docs-component-viewer-nav-content ng-tns-c139-5` rather than `mat-drawer-inner-container ng-tns-c36-0`:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container" *ngIf="shouldRun">
  <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened>Sidenav content</mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>Main content</mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

## Reproduction

As above, I use the `mat-sidenav-container` tag but don't know how to realize the Sidenav style of the official website one by one.

## Environment

- Angular: ~9.1.0
- CDK/Material:^9.2.0
- Browser(s): Chrome
- Operating System (e.g. Windows, macOS, Ubuntu): macOS

Answer (score 2):

Here is stackblitz **example** - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-drawer

Structure of angular sidenav menu

```
<button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
```

**mat-drawer-container** and **mat-drawer** are important

```
<mat-drawer-container fullscreen>
    <mat-drawer #sidenav mode="side" opened="true" role="navigation" style="background-color:#3c3f4e;">
      <ng-container>
          <mat-label>Test</mat-label>
      </ng-container>
    </mat-drawer>
    <mat-drawer-content role="region">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </mat-drawer-content>
  </mat-drawer-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/schematics#navigation-schematic)
you can use schematics to generate your full navigation and tweak the behaviour and the aspect as you like.

```
ng generate @angular/material:table <component-name>
```

The command above will create a fully responsive navigation component and it will import the necessary modules.

If you want to do it manually you can see the example below (basically what the command above will generate):

HTML template:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav
    #drawer
    class="sidenav"
    fixedInViewport
    [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
    [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
    [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false"
  >
    <mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 3</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="isHandset$ | async"
      >
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span>blog</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <!-- Add Content Here -->
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

TypeScript file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'it-nav-example',
  templateUrl: './nav-example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav-example.component.scss']
})
export class NavExampleComponent {

  isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.matches),
      shareReplay()
    );

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {}

}
```

CSS file

```
.sidenav-container {
  height: 100%;
}

.sidenav {
  width: 200px;
}

.sidenav .mat-toolbar {
  background: inherit;
}

.mat-toolbar.mat-primary {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

No matter how you choose to create the navigation make sure to place your routes inside the nav component in your root component like so:

app.component.html

```
<app-nav-example>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</app-nav-example>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently created a video tutorial on youtube that addresses this matter step by step.
Check it out here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XwNwtTeml3c

Thanks,
Liviu

Comment: Video is private and cannot be watched

Comment: I have published it again.

Comment: it's back offline